# How to clear Hive and Reinitialize it

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

in my app I'm using Hive for multi objects and used multi boxes for them.
I wanted to know is there any way to clear all of them at one and then Reinitialize the hive?
I need this for my app logout case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive is a lightweight and fast key-value database in Dart, commonly used in Flutter applications for local storage. To clear Hive and reinitialize it upon a user logging out, you'll need to do the following steps:

1. **Close all Hive boxes**: Ensure that all boxes are closed properly to avoid any potential errors or data loss.
2. **Delete the box files**: After closing the boxes, you can delete the files where Hive stores its data.
3. **Reinitialize Hive (if necessary)**: If you want to use Hive again after clearance, you may need to reinitialize it.

Here's a potential code implementation for these steps:

```dart
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;

// Call this method when the user logs out
Future<void> clearHiveAndReinitialize() async {
  // Close all boxes before deleting files
  await Hive.close();

  // Get the application's documents directory
  final appDocumentDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  // Hive stores its box files inside a directory called 'hive'
  final hiveDirectory = appDocumentDir.path + '/hive';

  // Use the dart:io library to delete the box files
  final hiveDir = Directory(hiveDirectory);
  if (hiveDir.existsSync()) {
    // Delete the directory recursively
    await hiveDir.delete(recursive: true);
  }

  // If you plan to re-use Hive after clearing it,
  // you might need to reinitialize it.
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  // Reopen your required boxes if needed
  // var yourBox = await Hive.openBox('yourBoxName');
}

// Usage: Call `clearHiveAndReinitialize` when logging out user.
```

Please note that if the application is set to use Hive throughout its operation, you'll likely want to reopen the necessary boxes you're using after clearing and reinitializing Hive.

Make sure you handle errors properly and inform users if something goes wrong during the process. Depending on the complexity of your app and the data you store, you may need to handle more than just clearing boxes, such as managing associated data in memory or resetting application state.